How to create the Denoise Autoencoder Model with the Pytorch for the time series?
guys!
Here is my code,am I right?
# 1.Dataset, I only use the 'capacity' column.
df = pd.read_csv("Final-CS2_35.csv")
# print(df.shape)  # 882*6
split = 0.8  
r = np.random.normal(0, 1, df['capacity'].shape)  
data = torch.from_numpy(df['capacity'].values).reshape(-1, 1).float()
data_res = torch.from_numpy(df['capacity'].values + r).reshape(-1, 1).float()  

train_len = int(len(data)*split)
lens = [train_len, len(data)-train_len]
train_data, val_data = random_split(data_res, lens)
# 2. create Model
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size * 2),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, hidden_size),
            nn.Tanh())
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size * 2),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hidden_size * 2, input_size),
            nn.Tanh())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
# 3.train the Model
def train_ae(model, train_loader, val_loader, num_epochs, criterion, optimizer):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # Training
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0
        for batch_data in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(batch_data)
            loss = criterion(outputs, batch_data)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_loss += loss.item()

        train_loss /= len(train_loader)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Training Loss: {train_loss:.4f}")

        # Validation
        model.eval()
        val_loss = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch_data in val_loader:
                outputs = model(batch_data)
                loss = criterion(outputs, batch_data)
                val_loss += loss.item()

        val_loss /= len(val_loader)
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}, Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}")
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), "one-DAE.pkl")

# DataLoader
batch_size = 8
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

ae1 = Autoencoder(input_size=1, hidden_size=128)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(ae1.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
train_ae(ae1, train_loader, val_loader, 50, criterion, optimizer)

# 4.predict
def make_predictions_from_dataloader(model, unshuffled_dataloader):
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load("one-DAE.pkl"))
    model.eval()
    predictions = []
    for x in unshuffled_dataloader:
        with torch.no_grad():
          p = model(x)
          predictions.append(p)
    predictions = torch.cat(predictions).numpy()
    return predictions.squeeze()


res_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, drop_last=True)
P = make_predictions_from_dataloader(ae1, res_loader)

# 5.Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))

plt.xlim(left=0, right=900)
plt.ylim(bottom=0, top=1.2)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.98, top=0.95, bottom=0.05)
font = {'family': 'Times New Roman', 'size': 16, 'weight': 'normal',}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)


plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(df['cycle'], data, linewidth=1.5, color='b')
plt.title('pure signal', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=20)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(df['cycle'], data_res, linewidth=1.5, color='r')
plt.title('noised signal', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=20)

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(df['cycle'][:880], P, linewidth=1.5, color='g')
plt.title('SDAE', fontname='Times New Roman', fontsize=20)

plt.show()

here is the LOSS and final picture
Epoch 1/50, Training Loss: 0.0339
Epoch 1/50, Validation Loss: 0.0334
Epoch 2/50, Training Loss: 0.0072
Epoch 2/50, Validation Loss: 0.0042
Epoch 3/50, Training Loss: 0.0048
Epoch 3/50, Validation Loss: 0.0030
Epoch 4/50, Training Loss: 0.0021
Epoch 4/50, Validation Loss: 0.0022
Epoch 5/50, Training Loss: 0.0018
Epoch 5/50, Validation Loss: 0.0020
Epoch 6/50, Training Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 6/50, Validation Loss: 0.0024
Epoch 7/50, Training Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 7/50, Validation Loss: 0.0018
Epoch 8/50, Training Loss: 0.0014
Epoch 8/50, Validation Loss: 0.0019
Epoch 9/50, Training Loss: 0.0017
Epoch 9/50, Validation Loss: 0.0021
Epoch 10/50, Training Loss: 0.0019
Epoch 10/50, Validation Loss: 0.0018
Epoch 11/50, Training Loss: 0.0013
Epoch 11/50, Validation Loss: 0.0020
Epoch 12/50, Training Loss: 0.0013
Epoch 12/50, Validation Loss: 0.0017
Epoch 13/50, Training Loss: 0.0012
Epoch 13/50, Validation Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 14/50, Training Loss: 0.0013
Epoch 14/50, Validation Loss: 0.0015
Epoch 15/50, Training Loss: 0.0015
Epoch 15/50, Validation Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 16/50, Training Loss: 0.0019
Epoch 16/50, Validation Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 17/50, Training Loss: 0.0013
Epoch 17/50, Validation Loss: 0.0024
Epoch 18/50, Training Loss: 0.0015
Epoch 18/50, Validation Loss: 0.0016
Epoch 19/50, Training Loss: 0.0012
Epoch 19/50, Validation Loss: 0.0022
Epoch 20/50, Training Loss: 0.0018
Epoch 20/50, Validation Loss: 0.0017
Epoch 21/50, Training Loss: 0.0012
enter image description here
I am trying to use SAE to perform noise reduction on the raw data, which has a shape of 882*6. I want to work on one of the columns, i.e. I want to perform noise reduction on the 'capaticy column'. I don't know if there is any problem if I write it this way? If there is a problem how do I need to change it? If there is no problem, what should I change if I want to become SDAE?

Welcome to StackExchange. As it stands, your question is a little "fuzzy" for this venue. How will you know when someone answers it correctly? If I'm honest, your image plots look ok (the output is denoised), and it looks like your SAE is training (i.e. the test and validation loss is reducing). I'm not really sure what more you want. I'd compare your results to a bog-standard denoising filter (i.e. not a learned one) and see if there is any difference.

Thank you for your answer.
There are two things I would like to know: 1. How do I measure if my code is correct, just a single look at the loss is appropriate?2. Ultimately, I am trying to implement SDAE, which is Stacked Denoise Autoencoder, how do I modify the Model in code?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
